# Running clang-query only on input files

Tags: clang, clang-query

I'm running clang-query on a specific file using a compilation database as follows:

```
clang-query -p build foo/bar.cpp
```

This works, but when I run a simple query (e.g. `match ifStmt()`) it returns thousands of results, including matches from imported headers and even the standard library.

Is there a way to restrict results to the file(s) that I launched clang-query with?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this can be done with the `isExpansionInMainFile` matcher ([reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html#narrowing-matchers)).

For example, the query would become `match ifStmt(isExpansionInMainFile())`.

Comment: You might want to consider `unless(isExpansionInSystemHeader())` instead, since you presumably do care about headers from your own project.